# Send file in HappyX

Tags: web, file-upload, nim-lang

Can I send file from server to client in HappyX web framework?

I have this project structure:

```
test/
-- assets/
   -- someImage.png
-- main.nim
```

How I can send `someImage.png` to client at route `/raw/someImage.png`?

```
serve "127.0.0.1", 5000:
  get "/raw/$assetName":
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily send file with two ways:

1. **Send one file directly**

```
serve "127.0.0.1", 5000:
  get "/raw/$file:string":
    return FileResponse("/assets" / file)
```

2. **Send any file from folder**

```
serve "127.0.0.1", 5000:
  # first - route, second - folder
  staticDir "/raw" -> "assets"
```